# OData/iPhone Error: The context is not currently tracking the entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, entity-framework, odata

I'm using [OData4ObjC](https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC) to have my iPhone app retreive/edit OData.

I've been able to successfully retrieve data, but when I try to delete some data:

```
Entities *proxy = [[Entities alloc]initWithUri:@"http://localhost:8080/Resource/example.svc" credential:nil];

//Creates and accesses the person object for the specified row
Model_date* selectedDate = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Project number: %@", selectedDate.getdate_project);  
[proxy deleteObject:selectedDate];
[proxy saveChanges];
```

It throws this error at deleteObject:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Exception', reason: 'Invalid Operation : The context is not currently tracking the entity.'

I know it's tracking the entity - my NSLog prints out the project project number.

DeleteObject is defined in [ObjectContext.h](https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC/blob/master/Framework/bin/odatalib/include/ObjectContext.h) (Framework/bin/odatalib/include), which I have added to my project path. I've tried to debug step by step but my [ObjectContext.m](https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC/blob/master/Framework/src/MSODataLib/Context/ObjectContext.m) is included is binary, so all I see is assembly.

[image]

Does anyone have any pointers/suggestions??